# RuntimeException or DomainException or LogicException in loader function?

Tags: architecture, php

Assume I have module of classes:

- `EntityLoader` loads some entity by id.
- `EntityValidator` checks preconditions, input data before saving changes.
- `EntityUpdater` saves changes.

`EntityLoader` has method `loadById($entityId)`, it loads data and caches it in own state. It is called in `EntityValidator` first, and is called in `EntityUpdater` later when validation has completed successfully.
Usage pattern is:

```
if ($validator->validate()) {
    $updater->update()
}
```

I want to see a not-nullable type of return value of function `EntityLoader::loadById($id)`. I want to throw `CouldNotFindEntityException`, when record cannot be loaded.
`EntityValidator` expects this exception. It catches this exception and produces respective result status. `CouldNotFindEntityException` looks like checked exception in terms of `EntityValidator` responsibility.

`EntityUpdater` should be called for successful validation result, thus I don't want to expect any exception from `EntityLoader` in `EntityUpdater` execution context. If I get exception there, it should mean either unrecoverable system error or developer code mistake. So `CouldNotFindEntityException` looks like unchecked exception in terms of updater action.

I write code in PHP and there is no checked/unchecked exception separation concept, so I can assume, that unchecked exceptions are inherited from `RuntimeException`, but checked exceptions are inherited from `DomainException`.

I can't realize which kind of exception should I use in my case? This is private for module exception, it isn't among observable behavior for client of module. It is domain-kind exception, because describes business logic problem in validator. In the same time, it is unrecoverable exception that looks like run-time in updater calling context.

Doesn't `LogicException` fit my needs for updater and validator?

I consciously choose exception mechanism for code simplification. I don't want to replace it with result status, or null-object, or Optional object.

Comment: ... the fact of the very large question implies a lack of simplification by choosing exceptions over another mechanism. As for checked/unchecked, this is not a thing in PHP. What is a thing is *when* you choose to throw. What is the *when*? If its an external factor, Runtime is most accurate. If it was a business rule violation choose domain. If the problem was that `2 + 2 == 5` then throw that logic bomb, nothing makes sense.

Comment: Can you absolutely guarantee that the entity won't be deleted from the database between the point where you retrieve it for validation and where you retrieve it again for updating? If you can't, failure to retrieve the entity for update should be an expected result.

Comment: Hi @Bart, yes, if entity deleted in db, it is still cached in Loader after first load for Validator, Updater doesn't read entity from db again. If entity missed in db, then we'd get another exception little bit later, when saving record to db (Optimistic Locking Exception). validate() always checks for update(), like Iterator::valid() checks position before we call Iterator::next().

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`DomainException`](https://www.php.net/DomainException) is not for application domains but for data domain violations ("domain" is used in the sense of the domain of a mathematical function, rather than business or problem domain, and corresponds to `RangeException`). For application domain exceptions, you'd need to create your own hierarchy.

Consider both the origin of the exception and how it would be resolved, rather than where it's caught. It originates in the system state and would be resolved by changing the state (removing the reference to the non-existent entity or adding the entity to the datastore). Both of these reasons point to `RuntimeException`. It doesn't indicate an implementation error and would not be resolved by a code change, which rules out `LogicException`. It also doesn't indicate an issue with an application model and wouldn't require a design change, which would rule out any hypothetical application domain exception.

`EntityUpdater`'s expectation that `EntityLoader->loadById()` won't throw a runtime exception is met by `EntityLoader`'s caching mechanism (as you mention in a comment). If you want the design to explicitly enforce this (i.e. it's a requirement), there are various approaches you could take:

- One would be to write another method that (logically) wouldn't throw (perhaps a method that refreshes a cached entity, ignoring requests for entities that aren't cached) and call that from `EntityUpdater->update()`. As this might be conceptually leaky and increase the surface of `EntityLoader`, it's not a very desirable solution.
- Another approach would be to view

  > `EntityLoader->loadById()` won't throw a runtime exception during calls by `EntityUpdater`

  as an unreasonable requirement and rewrite it both as a requirement for `EntityLoader`, making the caching behavior explicit:

  > After a load call on an `EntityLoader`, subsequent load calls won't throw `CouldNotFindEntity` until [list of circumstances that will invalidate the cached entity and require a load from the datastore].

  and a precondition for `EntityUpdate->update()`:

  > The entity to update will have been loaded before the update call.